# Null Adapter with Empty List after switching to GSON

Tags: android, gson

So I recently converted much of my JSON parsing to GSON because it is a very clean way to write code and also for performance.

However,  when any listView is empty now, I get a crash when setting the adapter.

*Note:  I am already using `lv.setEmptyView();`*

In my `task`, I collect the Network Data with `GSON` and stuff them into `ArrayList<Object>`.

Like this:

```
      // parse result
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType();
      ArrayList<Item> myItemsList = gson.fromJson(result.toString(), collectionType);
```

Then in my `onPostExecute()`, when I set the `adapter` like this:

```
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            miAdapter = new MyItemsAdapter(getActivity(), myItemsList,user_num);
            lv.setAdapter(miAdapter);  // NULL POINTER HERE IF LIST IS EMPTY
        }
```

I get a `nullpointer` when this list is empty:

Here is the exact `LogCat`:

```
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691): Process: com.---.---, PID: 17691
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at com.---.---.MyItemsFragment$MyItemTask.onPostExecute(MyItemsFragment.java:131)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at com.---.---.MyItemsFragment$MyItemTask.onPostExecute(MyItemsFragment.java:77)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
04-06 10:21:31.426: E/AndroidRuntime(17691):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

The `adapter` is being set, but how come when passing any empty list do I get this error?

- **Note**:  I just found this error after I converted everything to `GSON`.  However,  I accept the idea that it could have been there prior to this so maybe the only relevant issue is the empty list and the `adapter` and not `GSON` itself.

Comment: You can handle emptiness using `setEmptyview`. http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/. But you should check why your list is empty and fix it

Comment: @Raghunandan I actually am using the `setEmptyView` (I edited above to make note).  Also, it is perfectly legitmate that a `ListView` is empty in these cases.

Comment: following the blog post should help narrow the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  your **onPostExecute** method you are using

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
     miAdapter = new MyItemsAdapter(getActivity(), myItemsList,user_num);
     lv.setAdapter(miAdapter);  // NULL POINTER HERE IF LIST IS EMPTY
}
```

Hence you had check for activity but you don;t put check for **myItemsList** may be null so, you can initialize empty list here like this before pass it to the adapter...

```
if(myItemsList == null){
     myItemsList = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

You can handle the issue in some other way as well.. but this is the simple one..

**Edit :**

Actually the reason is when you are passing list in adapter 
your adapter's **getCount()** method will return the **size of list**
but when you are passing null in adapter... It will crash the app..  `NullPointerxception`

So, you can manage at that side as well by putting check for

```
if(list == null){
     return 0;
}else{
     return list.size();
}
```

but you **should never pass the null list in adapter**..

For best practices :

**Declare your list global and add element in list after parsing from gson and notify adapter for data-set changed**

let me know if anything needed...

Comment: I had thought of this and will do this of course, but it seems like it is not fixing the greater problem.  Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Ok, your original answer was enough after I reread,  I think when I updaged my code with the GSON stuff I moved some things around and forgot to originally instantiate my lists with `new ArrayList<Item>();`

Comment: Just an update, it was actually the second part of your answer that fixed this.  I had to override `getCount` in the `adapter` and add that.